# How does implicit conversion kick-in in example from "Programming in Scala"?

Tags: scala, yield, implicit-conversion

In [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) [7.8 Refactoring imperative-style code](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html#7.8):

```
// Returns a row as a sequence
def makeRowSeq(row: Int) =
  for (col <- 1 to 10) yield {
    val prod = (row * col).toString
    val padding = " " * (4 - prod.length)
    padding + prod
  }
// Returns a row as a string
def makeRow(row: Int) = makeRowSeq(row).mkString
// Returns table as a string with one row per line
def multiTable() = {
  val tableSeq = // a sequence of row strings
    for (row <- 1 to 10)
    yield makeRow(row)
  tableSeq.mkString("\n")
}
```

It appears that `yield makeRow(row)`somehow uses the 'Returns a row as a string' version of `makeRowSeq`. How does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the return from `makeRowSeq` is evaluated before the call to `mkString` so that the `makeRow` call is actually returning one string.  That is, it's using Sequence's mkString method instead of applying the function to each individual item of the sequence.  To do that you'd need a map function call.